# Upload Image / Make Post Request via curl + scrot + xclip

Tags: json, bash, post, curl

I am attempting to write a simple bash script that works similar to [jomo/imgur-screenshot](https://github.com/jomo/imgur-screenshot), but uses the [ziggi/zimg-host](https://github.com/ziggi/zimg-host) source.

Essentially what imgur-screenshot does is when the script is initialized, it opens up `scrot -select` (the -select option interactively choose a window or rectangle with the mouse). Then once you take the screenshot of the defined area, it uploads the saved screenshot to imgur (or in my case, my self-hosted site using ziggi/zimg-host) and then with xclip it copies the needed result data (ultimately the URL link) to your clipboard.

This is my (very base) bash script that I have now to perform this wanted purpose:

```
#!/bin/bash

function uploadImage {
        curl -s -F files[]="@$1" http://ziggisite.com/upload.php
}

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
        notify-send "Upload error"
else
        uploadImage $1 | xclip -selection c
        notify-send "Upload complete"
fi
```

When I initiate this script using the following command: `scrot -e './img.sh $f'`, it uploads a screenshot successfully but xclip does not copy the correct data to my clipboard - instead it copies everything that gets outputted.

And for reference, ziggi/zimg-host response looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name":"image1.jpg",
        "type":2,
        "size":
        {
            "width":420,
            "height":336,
            "filesize":26834
        },
        "error":
        {
            "upload":0,
            "type":0,
            "size":0
        },
        "url":"ccc762c11f336cfa9fdbcc1b7ea4c1a3.jpg"
    }
]
```

Basically once the script is ran, I need it to copy the "url" portion of the response, and throw`http://ziggisite.com` at the beginning of it, so the final data copied to my clipboard would look something like`http://ziggisite.com/ccc762c11f336cfa9fdbcc1b7ea4c1a3.jpg`.

If anyone could throw out some resources or assistance, that would be great!

Comment: Get a JSON parser. My favorite is [stedolan/jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq).

Comment: @4ae1e1 I grabbed jq and attempting to use it to parse for the URL value, however the closest I can get is the entire result which includes `{"url":"ccc762c11f.jpg"}`. I'm using `jq '.[0] | {url}'`. How can I alter that to just grab `ccc762c11f.jpg`

Comment: Have you read the manual? `jq`'s DSL is very simple. When you face a DSL you don't guess or invent your own syntax; instead, you go RTFM (read the f* manual). Anyway, I'll write an answer for your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP's comment I assume he/she is okay with using a JSON parser like `jq`. Then here's a solution in `jq`. Say we put the example response in `response.json`, then

```
<response.json jq -r '.[0].url'
```

yields

```
ccc762c11f336cfa9fdbcc1b7ea4c1a3.jpg
```

while

```
<response.json jq -r '"http://ziggisite.com/" + .[0].url'
```

yields

```
http://ziggisite.com/ccc762c11f336cfa9fdbcc1b7ea4c1a3.jpg
```

Here the `-r` option is for raw output, i.e., without JSON's quotes.